# How to get specific date and time string from big string

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, timestamp

i want to get `date` and `time` from this kind of `timestamp` `string`

```js
var t = "2017-10-28 10:46:20".split(/[- :]/);

// Apply each element to the Date function
var d = new Date(Date.UTC(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]));

console.log(d);
```

I want my desired result to be like below :

```
Sat Oct 28 2017  at 10:46 am
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in vanilla js however I would use the [Moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library which makes working with any type of date formatting super simple.

In your example you would just need to do this

```
const timeStamp = '2017-10-28 10:46:20';
const date = moment(timeStamp).format('ddd MMM do YYYY [at] HH:mm:ss A');

//date => 'Sat Oct 2017 at 10:46:20 AM'
```